# Making sure NPM dev dependencies match corresponding peer dependencies

Tags: npm, peer-dependencies

I pretty much always end up adding my NPM modules peer dependencies to dev dependencies as well because I need the peer dependencies installed so I can run automated tests before building the package. This creates the problem that I might accidentally use different version number for *peer* and *dev*. I find it odd that *npm* and *yarn* do not install the peer dependencies automatically when I run `npm install` or the `yarn` command. In some cases I have found that `yarn` even tries to prevent me from adding the same dependency as both *peer* and *dev* dependency. I think I'm doing something wrong but I haven't been able to figure out the intended workflow. Can someone explain to me how this is supposed to work?